# Get recommended videos with powershell on Youtube

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

When I open any video with powershell it turns out the recommended videos on the right side.

I tried to solve the problem in two ways.But neither of them gives the results I want.

**way 1**

```
$URI = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpeuIu-ZYJY'
$HTML=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('ytd-compact-video-renderer') | Where{ $_.className-eq 'style-scope ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer' } |  ForEach-Object { $_.getElementsByTagName('a') } |  Select-Object -Expand href
```

**way 2**

```
$URI = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpeuIu-ZYJY'
$HTML=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
$HTML.Links | Where href -like '/watch*' | select outertext,href
```

how do i download recommended videos on the right?
Sample video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrYlcytsBdE

Can you help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of recommended video's like this:

```
$URI = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpeuIu-ZYJY'
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
$HTML.Links | Where-Object { $_.href -like '/watch*' -and (!(!$_.title)) } | fl title,href
```

As for downloading, you could try using [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)